# What's the difference between "projects" and "files" windows in NetBeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans-7

I find "projects" window/panel including all the functionality of "files". I'm afraid I miss something, hence the question. If not, what's the redundancy for?

I use NB for HTML5/PHP development, I suppose there may be a difference in Java projects.

Greetings
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files shows all files/folders in project the way you can see them in external file manager (like explorer, tc, nautilus, finder...) while Projects shows projects - how IDE interprets files/folders in your project and e.g. context menu is different. Also Projects could show nodes that do not represent any folder/file, but some part of project.

For instance for PHP, if you add some folder to ignored files (via project properties), it is not visible in Projects, but you can still see it in Files in case you need it. In HTML5 project, Projects will always show "Site root" for all HTML5 projects, but files will show exact folder name (could be different in each project)

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now - Projects show files more in an "abstract" way. I think it means that if you use external filemanager there is almost no need for files tab. At least for me at this point.

I accept the answer, thx.